# How to specify header files in setup.py script for Python extension module?

Tags: python, distutils

How do I specify the header files in a setup.py script for a Python extension module? Listing them with source files as follows does not work. But I can not figure out where else to list them.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from glob import glob

setup(
    name = "Foo",
    version = "0.1.0",
    ext_modules = [Extension('Foo', glob('Foo/*.cpp') + glob('Foo/*.h'))]
)
```

Comment: Try importing setuptools rather than distutils.core. Then I believe it will pick up header files automatically. If that doesn't work, add a MANIFEST.in  as below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add *MANIFEST.in* file besides setup.py with following contents:

```
graft relative/path/to/directory/of/your/headers/
```

Comment: Doesn't that tell distutils to install the headers? I don't want to install the headers; they should only be used as input for the compiler. Only the pyd file produced by the compiler should be installed.

Comment: No, whey won't be installed. MANIFEST is not for installation, but for source distribution (setup.py sdist).

Comment: Great! But I'm surprised that you need a MANIFEST at all to do something this simple.

Comment: Gah, I can't believe I forgot about MANIFEST.in. >.<

Comment: Well, distutils can’t distribute files it knows nothing about.  C sources are included because they are registered with the Extension class, but header files need to be in MANIFEST or MANIFEST.in

Comment: @Éric Araujo: I'm suprised to learn that distutils knows about source files but not about header files.

Comment: I think it does not know about header files because it does not have to: given paths to C files and include dirs, a C compiler toolchain can do its work.  That’s probably why there is no headers parameter in the Extension class initializer.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use `recursive-include include *.h` inside MANIFEST.

Comment: Reference with more details: https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/

Answer (score 8):

Try the headers kwarg to setup(). I don't know that it's documented anywhere, but it works.

```
setup(name='mypkg', ..., headers=['src/includes/header.h'])
```

Comment: That should indeed work.  I have no idea whether the doc was omitted by oversight or if it was supposed to be an internal detail.

Comment: @Éric Araujo: I tried it, and it did not work. I did "setup.py sdist", and the headers were not included in Foo-0.1.0.zip.

Comment: There is actually a note in the code of the sdist command that says headers are not included, and another note in build_ext (which defines a get_source_file function used by sdist to build a part of its list of files) that says “Wouldn't it be neat if we knew the names of header files too”.  distutils is closed to new features (we work on distutils2 now), but I am inclined to consider this a bug and fix it for the next releases of Python 2.7 and 3.2.  I will open a report on bugs.python.org later.

Comment: @ÉricAraujo could you add a link to the bug report? I can't find it.

Answer (score 6):

I've had so much trouble with setuptools it's not even funny anymore.
Here's how I ended up having to use a workaround in order to produce a working source distribution with header files: I used package_data.

I'm sharing this in order to potentially save someone else the aggravation. If you know a better working solution, let me know.

See here for details:
https://bitbucket.org/blais/beancount/src/ccb3721a7811a042661814a6778cca1c42433d64/setup.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#setup.py-36

```
    # A note about setuptools: It's profoundly BROKEN.
    #
    # - The header files are needed in order to distribution a working
    #   source distribution.
    # - Listing the header files under the extension "sources" fails to
    #   build; distutils cannot make out the file type.
    # - Listing them as "headers" makes them ignored; extra options to
    #   Extension() appear to be ignored silently.
    # - Listing them under setup()'s "headers" makes it recognize them, but
    #   they do not get included.
    # - Listing them with "include_dirs" of the Extension fails as well.
    #
    # The only way I managed to get this working is by working around and
    # including them as "packaged data" (see {63fc8d84d30a} below). That
    # includes the header files in the sdist, and a source distribution can
    # be installed using pip3 (and be built locally). However, the header
    # files end up being installed next to the pure Python files in the
    # output. This is the sorry situation we're living in, but it works.
```

There's a corresponding ticket in my OSS project:
https://bitbucket.org/blais/beancount/issues/72

Answer (score 4):

If I remember right you should only need to specify the source files and it's supposed to find/use the headers.

In the setup-tools manual, I see something about this I believe.

"For example, if your extension requires header files in the include directory under your distribution root, use the include_dirs option"

```
Extension('foo', ['foo.c'], include_dirs=['include'])
```

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#preprocessor-options

Comment: Tried ext_modules = [Extension('Foo', glob('Foo/*.cpp'), include_dirs=['Foo'])]. Does not work; the header files are not added to the package.

Comment: Have you tried the code in your questions example? It *might* work, at least I hope it will. :) I couldn't find anything else related to your problem in the manual; sorry. :(

Comment: I added the include_dirs parameter. It seems to require an absolute directory and not a relative one as the build is carried out in the build dir and .h files are not copied across.

Comment: Seems like an option is proposed. Ref : https://bugs.python.org/issue34012